# How can I convert specific text to link within a div node?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, replace

**NOTE**: The first requirement for this is that it *not* use jQuery.
I also do not want to use `.innerHTML` if I can avoid it (even if that requires a bit more code)

I have divs within a page (multiple locations) that will be something like this:

```html
<div class="p-user-content">John Smith current working on ticket LQ-1954</div>
    ... again, multiple locations ...
<div class="p-user-content">Sally Jones <a href="[something]">assigned</a> GM-3398 yesterday</div>
```

There will be simple text, **and** tags like `<a>` mixed in with the text as shown.

The following script successfully identifies all the "text nodes":

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('p-user-content');
for (var i in el) {
    if (typeof el[i].childNodes === 'undefined') continue
    for (var k in el[i].childNodes) {
        if (typeof el[i].childNodes[k] === 'function') continue
        if (el[i].childNodes[k].nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE) continue

        /**
         This successfully gets the nodeValue
         */
        console.log(el[i].childNodes[k].nodeValue)
    }
}
```

What I want to do is split the text node word-by-word, and then convert values like `LQ-1954` and `GM-3398` to anchor elements, and then replace the modified text and anchor links back into the existing div.  I'm able to split the text up and do the matching part, but how would I

1. build the nodes back with the new links and
2. replace it back into the same div?

Comment: An anchor element without a `href` element does nothing useful (though `href="#"` can get around this to some effect); but what's the purpose of their being made into anchor links? What should the `href` be set to?

Comment: _"but how would I a) build the nodes back with the new links"_ - document.createElement, document.createTextNode, appendChild ... _"and b) replace it back into the same div?"_ - replaceChild, insertBefore, ...

Comment: If you are splitting up one text node into multiple new text/element nodes, then it probably makes most sense to insert the new nodes before the existing text node first, and then remove that textnode afterwards.

Comment: (And if any of your target texts could ever occur inside a link already, you'd have to check what parent node(s) your current text node has. Inside `<a href="...">foo GM-3398 bar</a>`, you would not want to replace the `GM-3398` with an additional link ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use .replace

```
document.body.outerHTML = document.body.outerHTML.replace(/(LQ-1954)/g , '<a> $1 </a>')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must avoid manipulating html by changing the value of `innerHTML`,
create a new element and replace the old element with it:

```js
function addLinks(){
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('p-user-content');
for (var i in el) {
if (typeof el[i].childNodes === 'undefined') continue
let value = el[i].innerHTML.replace(/[A-Z]{2}-[\d]{4}/g, (match)=>'<a href="#">' + match + '</a>');
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div')
  newDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", value);
  el[i].replaceChildren(newDiv)
}
}
```

```html
<div class="p-user-content">John Smith current working on ticket LQ-1954</div>
    ... again, multiple locations ...
<div class="p-user-content">Sally Jones <a href="[something]">assigned</a> GM-3398 yesterday</div> 

<button onclick="addLinks()">Add Links</button>
```

Simple way using `innerHTML`:

```js
function addLinks(){
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('p-user-content');
for (var i in el) {
if (typeof el[i].childNodes === 'undefined') continue
el[i].innerHTML = el[i].innerHTML.replace(/[A-Z]{2}-[\d]{4}/g, (match)=>'<a href="#">' + match + '</a>');
}
}
```

```html
<div class="p-user-content">John Smith current working on ticket LQ-1954</div>
    ... again, multiple locations ...
<div class="p-user-content">Sally Jones <a href="[something]">assigned</a> GM-3398 yesterday</div> 

<button onclick="addLinks()">Add Links</button>
```